# Google Sheets how to sort two columns in ascending order

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet table and need to select a data range and sort data using two columns in ascending order.

I have tried the following and it does not work:

```
var range = sheet.getRange( vRowStartFan, 1, (sheet.getLastRow() - vRowStartFan), sheet.getLastColumn() );
range.activate();
sheet.sort(col, true).sort(1, true);
```

What should I do?
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Define `do not work`

Comment: does not provide the expected result
need to get the table sorted with two conditions
col variable
and col=1

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sortTipsByCurrentColumn( sheet, col ) {
var range = sheet.getRange( vRowStartFan, 1, (sheet.getLastRow() - vRowStartFan), sheet.getLastColumn() );      
range.activate();
range.sort( [{column: col, ascending: true}, {column: range.getColumn(), ascending: true}]);
```

}

using range.sort allows the usage of more than 1 column for sorting